# How to disable a certain key from the keyboard until a function is called upon at least once?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a game which has a pause feature. Once the player presses the escape key whilst a game is playing, the menu enables, once escaped is pressed again it disables the menu and resumes the game. But when i open my program and press escape without launching a game first the game crashes causes theirs no game to resume. How could i disable the escape key until at least one game has started.

I am using the Pygame-menu module by ppizarror to create my gui, iv'e tried looking up my question but no one has a clear answer. Below is the main parts of code from two different classes that handles the pause feature.

Class EntertheGauntlet:
    # a function used throughout the menus that disables the previous menu for 
    the new one to be displayed
            def resume_feature():
                # disables menu
                self.main_menu.disable()
                # resumes the game paused in the background by calling upon it 
    from the main gameloop
                self.game.main()

Class GUI:
            # a function used throughout the game that initiates when the new 
    game button is pressed
            def start_new():

```
            # disable previous menu
            self.main_menu.disable()
            # Start new game by calling variable from EscapeTheGauntlet.py
            self.game = EscapeTheGauntlet(self.window, clock, self.sfx)
            # sets this new updated screen to the new main window
            self.game.main()
```

The only solution i can see is disabling the escape key until the start new game feature is called upon at least once. Could you please show me how i would do that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting sounds unnecessarily complex. You cannot mess with the system drivers of the keyboard, or with the key-to-character mapping, because the user might be working in a different window with a different program where the escape key is needed.

Can't you re-write *your code* that handles the pause function to check whether there is a paused game? Initialize some variable with False when the application starts, and set it to True when the function you expect to be called is called.